# How to make a simple json array with push

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, push

If I have a blog post and I push comments with the line:

```
blogpost.comments.push({ username: "fred", comment: "Great"});
```

the comments section of JSON looks like this:

```
"comments":[{"0":{"username":"jim","comment":"Good",},"1":{"username":"fred","comment":"great"}}]
```

Ideally I'd like to see the JSON without the numerical additions ("0","1", etc) and flatter. Something like:

```
"comments":[{"username":"jim","comment":"Good"},{"username":"fred","comment":"great"}]
```

What do I need to change to get this?

Comment: How is that JSON generated? -i.e. where are you viewing it?

Answer (score 3):

Wait, is `blogpost.comments` a JavaScript array, or something else? If it were a JavaScript array, I don't see how executing the first line of code would update the JSON object as you described. I would expect it to automatically do what you expect, which is to push a new item on the end of the array.

In general, if you have an array `blogpost.comments`, with this value:

```
[{"username":"jim","comment":"Good"}]
```

and you execute:

```
blogpost.comments.push({ username: "fred", comment: "Great"});
```

You will most certainly end up with `blogpost.comments` having the value:

```
[{"username":"jim","comment":"Good"}, { "username": "fred", "comment": "Great"}]
```

Which leads me to believe that `blogpost.comments` is not actually an array, but something else. You should give the code for `blogpost.comments.push` if it is your own code.

So, basically ... make it an array, and it will work as you expect.